# How to show only those sellers who have created at-least one product

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one sellers table where sellerid column is `sno` and I have products table where sellerid is `sellerid` , I want to get those sellers who are not blocked (there is column named `flag` in sellers table) and have created at least one product so I write this(or maybe copy this)

```
SELECT e.*, count(*) AS count 
FROM sellers AS e  
left join products AS r ON e.sno = r.sellerid 
where NOT e.flag='1' 
GROUP BY e.sno
```

Now I do my logic through:

```
if($row["count"] == 1){
continue;
}
```

It is producing incorrect result

Comment: count(*) AS count what is this then

Comment: how to write this

Comment: @Akina this is also showing one having no products

Comment: @Akina thank you it is working now , i also have to use `if($row["count"] == 0)`

Comment: @Akina it is working with left join should I change , I will accept your answer please post , u guided me to use `count(r.sellerid)` this solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> -- fake table data
> CREATE TABLE sellers SELECT 1 sno, 0 flag UNION SELECT 2, 0 UNION SELECT 3, 0;
> CREATE TABLE products SELECT 1 sellerid UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2;
> SET sql_mode := '';
> ```

> ```
> -- initial query
> SELECT e.*, count(*) AS `count` 
> FROM sellers AS e  
> left join products AS r ON e.sno = r.sellerid 
> where NOT e.flag='1' 
> GROUP BY e.sno
> ```
>
> | sno | flag | count |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 0 | 2 |
> | 2 | 0 | 1 |
> | 3 | 0 | 1 |

> ```
> -- counting joined values, not rows (NULLs are ignored)
> SELECT e.*, count(r.sellerid) AS `count` 
> FROM sellers AS e  
> left join products AS r ON e.sno = r.sellerid 
> where NOT e.flag='1' 
> GROUP BY e.sno
> -- further filtering by count>0 needed
> ```
>
> | sno | flag | count |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 0 | 2 |
> | 2 | 0 | 1 |
> | 3 | 0 | 0 |

> ```
> -- join only rows which have matched rows in second table
> SELECT e.*, count(*) AS `count` 
> FROM sellers AS e  
> inner join products AS r ON e.sno = r.sellerid 
> where NOT e.flag='1' 
> GROUP BY e.sno
> -- no further filtering needed
> ```
>
> | sno | flag | count |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 0 | 2 |
> | 2 | 0 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b977a9fda62c1b1a4e6df368c280377f)*